# Unique Geometry Theorem proof

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, plane-geometry

So have a look at the figure below :

[image]

Let me list out the given information :

> $1.$ $\angle ACB$ is a right angle
> $2.$ $\Delta BCD$ is an equilateral triangle

To show that :
$\angle BAE = 2 \hspace{0.1cm} \angle EAC$

I have been struggling with this question that I came up with on my own while proving that we can indeed trisect any angle given to us.

I started by using the original method of angle chasing, but then I realized that we keep going round and round back to where we started.

Then I resorted to trigonometry and sine and cosine rule of triangles but in that, too, I kept returning back to the same point.

Any ideas on how I should prove the theorem ?

Comment: Are you sure this question is correct? Can you tell me where you found it?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. I invented it on my own. It is relate to trisection of an angle. I have drawn countless triangles like this and in each one the theorem of ∠BAE=2∠EAC holds true.

Comment: Considering that this is essentially equivalent to trisecting an angle with a straightedge and compass, it is impossible for it to be true in general.

Comment: @Rushy that's exactly what I was thinking. But, I also tried it with some "popular angle choices" and found it to be true. Looks strange.

Comment: @doetoe can you elaborate a little?

Comment: I tried geogebra and got this is not valid. https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5yrD.png

Comment: @ACB can you maybe add a link...

Comment: I added a photo.. for some angles it seems to be so **approximately**. But the above diagram shows a significant difference.

Comment: Let  $a=BC$, $A = \angle BAC$ and $\alpha = \angle EAC$. Then eliminating $AC=h$ between $\tan A = a/h$ and $a / \sin \alpha = h / \sin (30^\circ - \alpha)$ gives the relation between $A$ and $\alpha$. It is not true that $A = 3 \alpha$ in general.

Comment: got it ! The theorem is wrong !!

Comment: @dvix You're right! I'll delete my comment!

Comment: @SayanDutta My comment was irrelevant

Comment: If it is true, we have a geometric construct of the trisection angle because of $\angle CAE=\angle BAC/3$! That's not true!

Comment: A quick & dirty calculation shows that the claim is only true if $\angle BAC$ equals $30^\circ$ or $45^\circ$.